# How do I fix my camera?

Tags: camera, media-scanner

I have a Samsung Admire (running Android 2.3) & my camera won't work: it keeps saying cannot connect to camera & it always says multimedia scanning. I'm not sure but I think some pics have been deleting little by little. Could it be from the scanning?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the SD card in your phone has some filesystem corruption. This can make the media scanner hang, can interfere with the camera, and can cause lost files. To check, and to fix it, try putting the SD card in a card reader attached to your PC, and using the disk check functionality there (e.g. `fsck` on Linux).